# Laravel use package in own project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm building a package in `Laravel 5.5`. Now I want to use that package
locally in my own project.

The composer.json from my package looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "larsjanssen6/underconstruction",
    "license": "MIT",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/larsjanssen6/underconstruction",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Lars Janssen",
            "email": "larsjanssen64@gmail.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php" : "^7.0",
        "illuminate/support": "~5.5.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "LarsJanssen\\underconstruction\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "LarsJanssen\\underconstruction\\UnderConstructionServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

(https://github.com/larsjanssen6/underconstruction)

In a fresh laravel project I've added the package like this in my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/larsjanssen6/underconstruction"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "larsjanssen6/underconstruction": "master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

But I receive this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package larsjanssen6/underconstruction could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Where did you publish you package? Git? Do you configured some package repository like the packagist? I could not find it.

Comment: Yes it's on git: https://github.com/larsjanssen6/underconstruction. In the second code block in my post you can see I've configured `repositories`.

Comment: You need to requite `dev-master` (always prefix with `dev-`, if you want to require a branch not tag or in GitHub's jargon release).

Comment: humm... sorry. I never have used the repository entry to set a necessary package to my project. Have you run the ```composer update``` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved answer from comment section.

You need to require `dev-master` in order to get [master's branch code](https://github.com/larsjanssen6/underconstruction/tree/master).

If you have some kind of other branch lets say `second-branch`, you would use `dev-second-branch` in your **composer.json** file.

```
...
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/larsjanssen6/underconstruction"
    }
],
"require": {
    ...
    "larsjanssen6/underconstruction": "dev-master"
},
...
```